# Why fullscreen slider doesn't show up on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've got [a website to maintain](http://wafflestory.ru/fr/) that have fullscreen slider based on *jquery superslides* plugin. The problem is - it disappears when window becomes 767px or less. And after spending few hours on looking through css file (media queries) and main.js file I can't find why this happens.
Looks like I don't see something obvious. Would be glad if someone like to solve such kind of puzzles :-)

Comment: Nice website but why did you change the scroll speed? :/

Answer (score 1):

give a height to:

```
.slider-wrapper,#slides {
height:100px!important;//change this to your suitable size
}
```

Comment: Used `height: 100vh !important;` and it worked perfectly! Thanks!

Comment: don't forget to check the green check :)